# Apache2 - Forward Secrecy - Grade capped to B

Tags: 20.04, apache2

I've just setup a new apache2 webserver and tested my site on ssllabs where I see this message "`This server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers. Grade capped to B.`"

I've searched and have found these to be added to vhosts file...

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

SSLHonorCipherOrder on

SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

However, the website post, where I got the above info from seems a few years old. Is anyone able to confirm if these can be improved further? If you need more info about any other settings please ask.

I am new and learning so wanted to check if it's safer to use the above and if there are any disadvantages etc.

Comment: Try not to put *too* much faith into the tests. You’ll find that most big corporations also get a B grade … unless they are a client of Qualys. Companies that use Qualys all seem to get an A+, which should raise an eyebrow 

Comment: @matigo - do you know if there are any other tests available? I want to check and see any issues flagged up.